# Colocation of Kafka Connect with AWS Hadoop instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

For production kind of setup, where TBs of records would be written onto the KAFKA topics, what is the best practice to use KAFKA connect - HDFS connector?

My kafka instance is running on AWS hostname a.b.c.d and my hadoop namenode is on AWS hostname p.q.r.s. For development/POC purposes, we have kept confluent in the same box as we have kafka instance running i.e. on a.b.c.d. The HDFS cluster size is 500GB.

But for production type setup where the cluster size would be 20-30 TB, is it advisable to keep confluent in the same box as KAFKA instance or in Namenode box or a separate box? How much separate disk size would confluent need in such a production case?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the Connect workers when you say "confluent" so this comment is based on that assumption. The most advisable thing to do is separate services where possible. Run the workers separately from the brokers, separately from the NameNode. Connect workers require very little disk space as they don't hold data (except offset data in standalone mode). In distributed mode, you can scale workers elastically so separating things is also better for the long term scalable setup.

For your use case, you really need to benchmark to make sure performance is acceptable if you want to run things in the same box. Figuring out whether it's ok to co-locate is really a consulting question that requires details of your use case to a level probably not appropriate for an online forum.